# Set the height of an include_graphics to the height of a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Consider the following tikz code:

```
\newcommand\Header{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (header) 
at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{header.png}};

\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (header_left) 
at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[height=
% SAME HEIGHT AS THE HEADER NODE ?
]{header_left.png}};

\draw [fill=nicedarkblue, draw=none] (header.south west) 
rectangle ($(header.south east)-(0,0.1cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

How to set the height of the second image to be equal to the height of the first one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better ways, but you could use the `let` syntax to calculate the height of the header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\Header{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node [below, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (header) 
at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=2cm]{example-image.png}};

\path
  let
    \p1=(header.south),
    \p2=(header.north),
    \n1={\y2-\y1)}
  in
 node[anchor=north,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  at (\p2)
  {\includegraphics[height=\n1]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\Header

Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]